# WordPress Custom php line code

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-function

I would like to add a small line of php to a post that already exists in WordPress im aded the code but after im publish it the code automatically convert to comment :

this that im add :
[image: code]

and this what i get :
[image: pic 2]

Comment: You cant add php code into post using wp editor. Read the docs

Comment: Please don't post images, use the proper code embedding options here on SO. If the image hoster removes the image, this question will become worthless.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the shortcodes, add some lines to the file functions then use the shortcode into your post

```
add_shortcode( 'php_code', function(){
echo "hello world";
} );
```

then use the `[php_code]` into your post